# On the performance of Bolt in the 100 metre sprint - solving equation of motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, drag

I'm looking at the following article([1](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1305.3947.pdf)) in which a mathematical model is used to describe the performance of Bolt (in general of a sprinter) in a 100 m sprint.
The equation of motion is
$$ m\dot u = F_0 -D(u) $$
where $u$ is the velocity, $F_0$ is the propulsive force (assumed constant) and $D(u)$ is a generic drag force. To solve it, a second order Taylor expansion of $D(u)$ is made so
the equation becomes $$ m\dot u = F_0 -\sigma u - \gamma u^2 $$
To get the velocity, integrate (setting $t_0 = 0,u_0=0$)
$$ \frac{t}{m}=\int_0^u \frac{du'}{F_0-\gamma u - \sigma u^2} $$
Now, the author skips the calculation and gives the following result:
$$ u(t)=\frac{AB(1-e^{-kt})}{A+Be^{-kt}}$$
giving the following relations: $$ \left\{
\begin{array}{l}
\sigma = km/(A+B)\\
\gamma = kmAB/(2A+2B)\\
F_0 = km(A-B)/(A+B)
 \end{array}
\right.$$

Basically, my problem is to find the relations for the coefficients A,B,k.
To do so, I solve the integral by factorizing the denominator, obtaining

$$ \frac{t}{m}=\sigma^{-1}\int_0^u \frac{du'}{(u'-u_-)(u'-u_+)} $$
where $u_\pm =\frac{\gamma \pm \sqrt{\gamma^2 +4F_0\sigma}}{2\sigma}$
then, decomposing,
$$\frac{\sigma t}{m}=a\Big[\int_0^u \frac{du'}{(u'-u_-)} - \int_0^u \frac{du'}{(u'-u_+)}\Big]$$
with $a=\frac{\sqrt{\gamma^2 +4 F\sigma}}{\sigma}$.

Continuing, $$\frac{\sigma t}{am}=ln(u-u_-)-ln(u-u_+) + ln\Big(\frac{u_+}{u_-}\Big)= ln\Big[\frac{(u-u_-)u_+}{(u-u_+)u_-}\Big]$$
So
$$ \frac{(u-u_-)}{(u-u_+)}=\frac{u_-}{u_+} exp\Big[\frac{\sigma t}{am}\Big]$$
Rearranging the terms I obtain
$$ u(t)=\frac{u_+u_-(1-e^\frac{\sigma t}{am})}{u_+-u_-e^\frac{\sigma t}{am}}$$

I see I can associate
$$ \left\{
\begin{array}{l}
k =\frac{ma}{\sigma} =\frac{m}{\sigma^2}\sqrt{\gamma^2-4F\sigma}\\
A = \frac{\gamma}{2\sigma}+\sqrt{\gamma^2-4F\sigma}\\
B = \frac{\gamma}{2\sigma}-\sqrt{\gamma^2-4F\sigma}\\
\end{array}
\right.$$
So
$$ u(t)=\frac{AB(1-e^{-kt})}{A-Be^{-kt}}$$
but the denominator as a minus sign. Can someone give me a hand or a hint?